# Jquery: change attributes of button and its siblings on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony

I have divs with buttons. If div is cover, the button's text is 'Cover' and it's disabled. Other buttons have text 'Set as cover' and are enabled. If I click on other button, it should change its text to 'Cover' and become disabled. The one that was 'Cover' should change to 'Set as cover' and become enabled.

**JavaScript**

```
function setCoverObject(id) {
    var url = "{{ path('collection_set_cover', {'id' : id}) }}";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
           $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            $(this).attr('value', 'Cover');
            $(this).siblings('.set_as_cover').prop('disabled', false);
            $(this).siblings('.set_as_cover').attr('value', 'Set cover');
        }
    });
}
```

**Twig**

```
{% for object in collection.objects %}
<div class="object">
<button id="cover_button_{{ object.id }}"class="set_as_cover"
                       onclick="setCoverObject('{{ object.id }}'); return false;">
                        Set cover
                    </button>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This code is not working, however after page reload all changes are applied.

Comment: what is ``this`` here? from where you are calling it?

Comment: Can you please post whole markup. including siblings..

Comment: @Vasimkhan I posted rest of the code

Comment: check my answer: you just need to `bind` the `success` callback to `this` value.

Comment: @DmitrySokurenko thanks, but it didn't help

Comment: And btw, you shouldn't set the title as button's value, you should set the button's content, so instead of `some_button.attr('value', 'Set cover')` use `some_button.text('Set cover')`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `setCoverObject` is an event handler, you need to bind the AJAX callback to `this` value. So:

```
success: function (data) {
  ...
}.bind(this)
```

And if it is not an event handler, then find your button element and bind the callback to it. E.g.:

```
var button = $("#id-of-your-button").get(0)
success: function (data) {
  ...
}.bind(button)
```

Also to set the button text you shouldn't use the button's value attribute you should set the button content, so instead of

```
some_button.attr('value', 'Set cover')
```

use:

```
some_button.text('Set cover')
```

Answer (score 0):

I added id to certain button and used .not to change other buttons.

```
 success: function (data) {
            $('.set_as_cover').not('#cover_button_'+objId).each(function(){
                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                $(this).text('Set cover');
            });
            $('#cover_button_'+objId).prop('disabled', true);
            $('#cover_button_'+objId).text('Cover');
        }
```